# Blocking in a thunk'd async request

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I have a submit handler firing off an action creator to emit an async request in reactjs:

```js
handleTimeSubmit = () => {
  // ...
  this.props.emitTimeRequest(arg1, guid);
  // setInterval should go here after checking response
}
```

The action creator should receive a 202 and a polling location, and does:

```js
export function emitTimeRequest(arg1, guid) {
  const URI = '/someplace';
  var config = {
    headers: {'X-Request-ID': guid}
  };
  return function (dispatch) {
    axios.post(URI, arg1, config)
    .then((response) => {
      if ( response.status === 202 ) {
        var timeID = setInterval(() => {
          dispatch(emitCheckTimeStatus(response.headers['content-location']));
        }, 1000);
        return {
          type: EMIT_TIME_SLICE_REQ_OK,
          payload: timeID
        }
      } else {
        dispatch(emitTxRxAlert("red", "server timeslice error " + response.status));
        return {
          type: EMIT_TIME_SLICE_REQ_NA,
          payload: response.status
        }
      }
    })
  };
}
```

However `setInterval` does NOT belong in the action creator (and I get lots of warnings in the console). If I put it in the submit handler the action creator function returns control to the caller before a response has been received from the server and I don't want to put some kludgy timer in the submit handler to force it to wait. Race condition.

Is there any way to force the action creator (`emitTimeRequest` above) to block until it receives the 202? Where should the `setInterval` be implemented?

Everything works fine, `emitCheckTimeStatus` does it's job and clears `timeID`.

Answer (score 0):

Moved the all the timer logic to `componentWillMount()` for the relevant component. All set.